# Network not working after apt upgrade & reboot in Xen virtual machine (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, xen

I have Ubuntu 18.04 domU running with a bridged network to a host NIC. Everything was working fine, until I did a apt upgrade and rebooted after that. Since then, domU networking has not been working, although dom0 network works fine. Apparently the domU is at least now using netplan, unlike the host which still uses old /etc/networking/interfaces config file.

Any ideas how to start debugging this?

```
foo@bar:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
foo@bar:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
foo@bar:~$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fe2b:d689  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:16:3e:2b:d6:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 174416  bytes 7259380 (7.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 78  bytes 17809 (17.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5352  bytes 380352 (380.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5352  bytes 380352 (380.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The bridge is using a different physical NIC than what the host is using. The bridged NIC is exposed to Internet, while the host NIC is not. I double checked that the cable is working by attaching it to a laptop.

Comment: The normal way to have a host machine disconnected from Internet and Guest Machine connected to Internet is with a  USB wireless card for the Guest. You neeed USB pass through.

Comment: Why would I use a USB wireless card, when I already have actual ethernet NICs? Also, I don't want to give the virtual machine access to physical devices.

Comment: I believe I'm currently experiencing the same issue - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/734470/xen-domo-has-network-but-domu-does-not

Comment: I'm currently updating from 18.04 to 20.04 I'll let you know if that resolves

Comment: updating to 20.04 did not resolve

Comment: I believe this might be another report: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454179/xen-ubuntu-host-to-guest-bridge-traffic-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be getting this bug described here:
[5.15.0-58.64 breaks xen bridge networking (pvh domU)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2002889)

tl;dr from that bug report is apparently this is a regresion related to a security fix. There's a fix currently being tested. The kernel version which has the potential fix is 5.15.0-**66**

#### To solve (best solution):

Wait. Bug fixes should come through as part of your usual `apt-get update` && `apt-get upgrade`. I'd wait a few days and try updating.

#### For an immediate fix (less recommended):

Subscribe to pre-releases to get the most up-to-date kernel.

1. Add `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-proposed main` to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` (note replace "bionic" with your current distro if you're using a different ubuntu version)
2. `apt-get update`
3. `apt-get full-upgrade` *

- Note that `apt full-upgrade` is necessary here, not simply `apt upgrade`, as many users are in the habit of typing. The full-upgrade portion of the command will instruct Ubuntu to also upgrade the system kernel. You will then need to reboot the system in order to utilize the new kernel.

Again the target version for the fix is 5.15.0.-66 so you should see a message like:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
linux-headers-5.15.0-66 linux-headers-5.15.0-66-generic linux-modules- 
extra-5.15.0-66-generic
```

when you run `apt-get full-upgrade`

Comment: Apparently the kernel is a lot older due to it being Ubuntu 18.04 - although the same bug might exist there as well. So lets see what happens in a few days. Luckily my virtual machine isn't anything critical.


`foo@bar:~$ uname -a
Linux bar 4.15.0-204-generic #215-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 18:24:59 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Oh right, I updated from 18.04 in troubleshooting so that makes sense. But still have good news - check out this comment on the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2002889/comments/17 
"The problem **does** occur on Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15.0-204
The problem does **not** occur on Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.15.0-206.217"

(So fix in progress)

Comment: Looks like installing HWE kernel to Dom0 helped as well...

"Bionic:
The problem does **not** occur on Ubuntu 18.04 with HWE-kernel 5.4.0-137 (-138 I did not test, sorry)
The problem does **not** occur on Ubuntu 18.04 with HWE-kernel 5.4.0-139 > fixed!"